# BizTalk Preserve Interchange - wrong root node

Tags: biztalk, edi, biztalk-2013

I've got a Party/Agreement with the setting "Preserve Interchange - suspend Interchange on error".  My understanding is that that's supposed to provide data with `http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/EDI/X12/2006/InterchangeXML` and a root "X12InterchangeXml".

Apparently the root is being set to X12_00401_820 as I'm getting the error below.

Error:

> 6: Finding the document specification by message type "`http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/EDI/X12/2006/InterchangeXML#X12_00401_820`" failed. Verify the schema deployed properly.`

I'm trying to reverse engineer an old system (from BT2010 to BT2013/R2) that has an orchestration with `http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/EDI/X12/2006/InterchangeXML` and a root "X12InterchangeXml".  I have the code and the bindings, but not the party definition, so I'm taking test data and building on my party/agreement for the 820 to try to recreate what they were doing before.

References:

[EDI Batch Schemas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/edi-batch-schemas)

[BizTalk Server: Working with Preserve Interchange EDI Xml (Part 1)](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/26691.biztalk-server-working-with-preserve-interchange-edi-xml-part-1.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the error namespace was really from the outbound part of the receive port, not the inbound part.  I had a map to the 820 specified in the message, but that 820 schema was not deployed.